# Bootstrap custom button border appearing only on hovering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently designing a webpage using bootstrap. I needed a custom button color, so I designed my own button classes, which you can see there:

```
 .btn.btn-radio {
    background: #f3bb70;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: #684235;
}

.btn.btn-plus {
  background: #684235;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

Since the button group is of the same color I wanted to put a border only on the right side, to show the separation. But the border appears only when the mouse is over the button (see https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20757/ ). Why is it so ? How do I make it be there all the time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has to do with the z-index of the buttons so to fix the problem without mixing up with the margin you need to  put borders to all the buttons then remove the first-child left border

```
.btn.btn-radio {
    background: #f3bb70;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: #684235;
    border-left-color: #684235;
}
.btn.btn-radio:first-child{
    border-left-color: transparent;
}

.btn.btn-plus {
    background: #684235;
    border-color: transparent;

}
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I get this right, basically both borders were at the same position so it showed only one at a time ?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has this line in css. This creates problem.

```
.btn-group .btn+.btn, .btn-group .btn+.btn-group, .btn-group .btn-group+.btn, .btn-group .btn-group+.btn-group {
      margin-left: -1px;
 }
```

You can use this, but i dant know if it will not make some other problems:

```
 .btn.btn-radio {
    background: #f3bb70;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: #684235;
    margin-left: 0!important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to override the `.btn` in bootstrap.css file

it currently has

`border:1px solid transparent;` and hence your border is not showing normally